# filter out the longest string in purr

Tags: r, purrr

Consider this example

`list('test', 'one')`

I would like to subset this list and only keep the longest string in the list. Using `purrr::keep` does not seem to work.

```
> list('test', 'one') %>% keep(~ nchar(.x) == max(nchar(.)))
[[1]]
[1] "test"

[[2]]
[1] "one"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Look at `purrr::reduce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `l` is stored, then indeed base R seems best:

```
l <- list('test', 'one')

# If you want only the first one or there is a unique element
l[which.max(nchar(l))]
# [[1]]
# [1] "test"

# General
l[nchar(l) == max(nchar(l))]
# [[1]]
# [1] "test"
```

Now with `keep` we may do

```
list('test', 'one') %>% keep(function(x) nchar(x) == max(nchar(.)))
# [[1]]
# [1] "test"
```

The issue appears to be that both `.` and `.x` are just individual elements of the list in `~ nchar(.x) == max(nchar(.))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do simple:

```
k <- list('test', 'one')
k[which.max(lapply(k, nchar))]

[[1]]
[1] "test"
```

Comment: yes thanks I know I can use base R. I wonder if there is a `purrr` solution here. thanks!

Comment: I don't think so because to do this, one must needs to store the `nchar` value and only after that the max value can be calculated.